# What happens when another process updates a record while I'm reading in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Suppose I have this script in C#

```
  ....
  string _commandStr = "SELECT * FROM products";

  if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
       connection.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_commandStr, connection);
  var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read())
  {
      ...some expensive formatting operation. This cycle takes minutes
  }
```

Now what happens if another process appends a Record to the products table while the READ cycle is running ? Will the final record be available before the cycle ends ?

Comment: Read up on isolation levels.

Comment: the behaviour here will vary between RDBMS and between isolation levels

Comment: `...some expensive formatting operation. This cycle takes minutes` don't do that. Keeping a transaction open for long *blocks* other connections that may be trying to modify the data. Even if you use snapshot isolation you'll pay for the long transactions in increased tempDB usage. Separate reading from processing, and read the data as quickly as possible. Formatting is typically associated with reporting though, and you should *never* run reports over live data. That's why separate reporting databases and fact tables are used, with different schemas suitable for reporting

Comment: One thing you can do is split reading and processing in separate parts. Read the data as quickly as possible and pass it to the processing step. If you use eg an ActionBlock you can configure it to use multiple threads to process the records send to it from the reader. SQL Server's SSIS processes data by using datalfows of connected blocks. You can do the same thing with TransformBlock, ActionBlock and the other classes of the TPL Dataflow library

Comment: Side notes: don't cache the connection, you should dispose connection, command and reader with `using` blocks, in which case you also don't need to check `connection.State` (because you are creating a new connection each tim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not a newly inserted (and committed) row is returned by the `SELECT` query depends on:

1. transaction current session [isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. the read committed snapshot database option
3. whether the the select query scan point is before or after the new row location.

With `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level in a database with the `READ_COMMITTED_SHAPSHOT` option off, the new row may or may not be returned depending on whether the newly inserted row is before before or after the `SELECT` query scan point.

With `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level in a database with the `READ_COMMITTED_SHAPSHOT` option on, the new row will not be returned. The query results reflect the data at the time the `SELECT` query began so newly inserted rows will not be returned.

With `SNAPSHOT` isolation level, the query results reflect the data at the time the `SELECT` query (or explict transaction) began so newly inserted rows will not be returned.

With `REPEATABLE_READ` isolation level, the new row may or may not be returned depending on whether the new row is before is inserted before or after the `SELECT` query scan point.

With `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, the new row will not be returned because concurrent inserts will be blocked during the `SELECT` query full scan.

Comment: What about uncommitted / nolock?

Comment: @mjwills, I didn't include `READ_UNCOMMITTED` in my answer because it shouldn't be used in production code and may cause even existing rows to be skipped or duplicated in the results.